# Why is `instance_eval`/`class_eval` not able to access class variables?

Tags: ruby, class-variables

```
class MySelf
  @@name = 'jonathan'
  def self.name
    @@name
  end
end

MySelf.instance_eval {@@name}
MySelf.class_eval {@@name}
```

both throw:

```
NameError: uninitialized class variable @@collection in Object
```

but

```
MySelf.instance_eval {name}
MySelf.class_eval {name}
```

both work.

How can I access the static var `@@name` with `instance_eval`/`class_eval`, or how can I assign a value from outside the class?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error thrown is because `MySelf.instance_eval('@@name')` correctly throws an error. This is not an instance variable, it's a class variable. You'll want to have `MySelf.class_eval('@@name')` on it's own, and then it'll work.

Check the repl here: https://repl.it/Be0U/0

To set the class variable, use `class_variable_set` like so:

```
 MySelf.class_variable_set('@@name', 'graham')
```

Comment: thanks, but I dont understand why this doesnt work: `MySelf.class_eval{@@name}` but this does work `MySelf.class_eval('@@name')`

Comment: The curly braces indicate a block, the brackets are passing parameters to a method.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use **class instance variable**.

```
class MySelf
  @name = 'jonathan'

  def self.name
    @name
  end
end

MySelf.instance_eval { @name } # => "jonathan"
MySelf.class_eval { @name }    # => "jonathan"
```

Try it, plz.